# Rewrite URL with three dynamic parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriting

I am working on my website where URL is something like:

```
http://mywebsite.com/series.php?sid=1&part=1&name=Introduction%20to%20HTML
```

I have tried a rule in my htaccess which is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ /series.php?sid=$1&part=$2&name=$3
```

In order to rewrite URL in form of:

```
http://mywebsite.com/1/1/Introduction to html.html
```

Unfortunately, it is not working for me.

Please someone help me in sorting out the issue. I would also love it if someone makes me understand how it worked.
I'm newbie for .htaccess. 
In above rule, I can see three different parts like:

```
1st part: ^([^/]+)
2nd Part: ([^/]+)
3rd part: ([^\.]+)\.html$
```

These three parts are separated by backslash. How they work and how can I utilize the same Rewrite URL form for more than 3 let say 4 or 5 parameters and less than 3 like 2 parameters?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is correct, just add `L` flag to end the rule and make sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled through Apache config.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ /series.php?sid=$1&part=$2&name=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm afraid. It is not working for me. Can you tell me for what purpose we added [L,NC,QSA] ?

I believe QSA is somewhat related to Query String. How about L?

Comment: L is for Last Rule, NS is for no case comparison and QSA is for (existing) query string append. You just need L flag but as I wrote make sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled through Apache config. If they are enabled then post your complete .htaccess within your question.

Comment: Hey thank you so much. 
I added [L...] my rule and it is working perfect. 

My bad, I was trying

http://localhost/series/1/1/Introduction%20to%20HTML.html

Instead of 

http://localhost/1/1/Introduction%20to%20HTML.html

Now it works perfect. Thank You!.